# javascript failed to set private variables

Tags: javascript, class

I have created a class-like structure with a private variable. The code is as follows:

```
var sinan = function(){
    var a = {ssss: 1};
    return {
        get: function(){
            return a;
        },
        set: function(s){
            a = {ssss: s}
        }
    }
}
```

When I do

```
sinan().get(); // outputs {ssss: 1}
sinan().set(2); 
sinan().get(); // outputs {ssss: 1}
```

It didn't output `{ssss: 2}`.  Does anyone know what is happening?  Thanks.

Comment: `sinan()` initializes `ssss: 1` Did you mean `new Sinan()`?

Comment: You are initializing sinan three times, hence it is correct. Perhaps you wanted a **static** class instead? http://jsfiddle.net/erbygoc7/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your "class" is not singleton `sinan()` constructs new instance every time with `a.sss` being equal to `1`.

What you want to do is to create only once instance and use it:

```
var s = sinan();
console.log( s.get() );
s.set(2); 
console.log( s.get() );
```

Of course you can make `sinon` singleton too if you want. For example, here is a simple implementation with instance stored in closure:

```
var sinan = function () {

    var instance;

    return function () {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = function() {
                var a = {ssss: 1};
                return {
                    get: function () {
                        return a;
                    },
                    set: function (s) {
                        a.ssss = s
                    }
                }
            }();
        }
        return instance;
    };
}();
```

So in this case `sinan() === sinan()`, i.e. `sinan()` returns the same object every time.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r07wgyjt/

Comment: +1 for pointing out about singleton functions: http://jsfiddle.net/erbygoc7/ <-- Example of **your** case with a signleton function.

Comment: Nice. Would have been better if you had placed all functional details outside return and just initialized instance with function name in return.
Something like this. ==> http://jsfiddle.net/r07wgyjt/1/

Comment: got it! and thanks for explaining the singleton case.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that each time you call `sinan()`, a new sinan instance is created, so it's the same as :

```
var s1 = sinan();
s1.get(); // 1
var s2 = sinan() ;
s2.set(2); // 2
var s3 = sinan();
s3.get(); // 3
```

You should be doing :

```
var s1 = sinan();
s1.get(); // 1
s1.set(2); // 2
s1.get(); // 2
```